# Get data from DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

How can I get data from **DataGrid** when ComboBox' text is equal with the record of the DataGrid:

```
combobox1.ItemsSource = database.Mahs.ToList();

combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "MahName";
```

and

```
private void datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = datagrid_customer.SelectedItem;
    string id = (datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(data) as TextBlock).Text;
    txt_f1.Text = id;
}
```

It shows me the id, but when i selected item but i want show me id when combobox.Text = name of the row in the DataGrid, then show the id of that row.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. 1: You select an item from ComboBox. 2: You select an item from DataGrid ? What should happen ? They should be compared to each other ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada  i want know how show id from datagrid when text of combobox equal  with name in datagrid

Comment: nobody can help?

Comment: Usually questions gets answered very quickly here. It might be very clear for you what you are asking about, but for everybody else it is still not clear. I would suggest you modify your question, and add more details, specially about the part where you explain what you exactly want. _Want to show id from datagrid when **text** of combobox equals with name in datagrid_ does not make any sense. 1: Datagrid has no ID. 2: Combobox does not have any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your approach slightly, and retrieving the entire object from both controls for the comparison. This way you have full access to the properties of each selected object.

If the objects you're retrieving from your database override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` you could do away with some of the if statements below. But to get you started here's a quick example of your change listener

```
private void datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Cast the objects from your DataGrid and your ComboBox. 
    YourDataObject dataItem = (YourDataObject)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
    YourDataObject comboItem = (YourDataObject)combo.SelectedItem;

    // Compare your objects and decide if they're the same. Ideally you would 
    // have Equals and HashCode overridden so you could improve this
    if (dataItem == null || comboItem == null)
        text.Text = "Not Matching";
    else
    {
        if (dataItem.MahName == comboItem.MahName)
            // You've got full access to the object and all it's properties
            text.Text = dataItem.Id.ToString();
        else
            text.Text = "Not Matching";
    }
}
```

Comment: The program crash . i think because we did not specify the row

Comment: When you call selected Item on the DataGrid it should return the object stored in that row. Could you let me know the name of the Object that `database.Mahs.ToList()` is returning?

Comment: Actually that is my problem. its not returning any object. its crashing before return any object.

Comment: @EmadShojaeenasab did this solve your question in the end?